# Not able to check scene processing status ( Forge Unity integration)

Tags: autodesk-forge

I used the following link (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/arvr-toolkit-refresher). I got the following output after step 2 in Postman ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgeTu.png)). So when I Proceeded to check the scene processing status, It returned an error. I also tried to view the model in unity, where it said 'AsyncRequestCompleted The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity. UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)'

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the trailing `=` characters from the model URN. These are not needed, and some endpoints of the Forge platform actually *require* you to remove them, so that might be the reason why you're getting the error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It worked. I feel so terrible because of this silly mistake. Also, can you please make sure that '=' is not present in URN value in the first place, it would help a lot of tthem

Comment: Another issue, I have a .nwd file which is (6mb)... While importing it into unity the progress is stuck at 0.02%, (I was able to import a 76kb one successfully). Can you please help me out here

Comment: No worries! As far as I know, the URN is usually created by you as the developer, by base64-encoding the ID of the object of your interest, so you can simply remove the trailing `=`s as part of the URN conversion.

Comment: Regarding the loading times in Unity: due to the way it's designed, the AR/VR Toolkit server can be a bit too slow when there are too many elements in your design. The server basically needs to retrieve all the individual object meshes from its storage system and combine them together, so if there are too many objects, things can get slow.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on a web service in order to get your Forge models into Unity, we have an alternative approach which is just a Node.js library (usable in other Node.js apps or as a command-line tool) that can convert your Forge models into glTF: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils. The glTF files can then be imported into Unity, Unreal Engine, A-Frame, or many other platforms.